# Why didn't poll observers use binoculars?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, presidential-election, contested-election

Apparently some of the lawsuits filed by the Trump campaign have protested the fact that their observers could not stand close enough to election workers to see the writing on mail-in ballots:

> In November, the state’s highest court upheld a Philadelphia judge’s ruling that state law only required election officials to allow partisan observers to be able to see mail-in ballots being processed, not stand close enough to election workers to see the writing on individual envelopes.

[Source](https://apnews.com/article/joe-biden-donald-trump-pennsylvania-elections-electoral-college-151f9a6ca176bd92bb67e4494fecc3c7)

This strikes me as a rather weird lawsuit to have, because there's an obvious workaround: the partisan observers could simply take out a pair of binoculars. They would be able to see the writing on individual envelopes while standing where they are, and everyone would be happy.

What's wrong with this workaround?

Comment: Try reading something laying flat on a table 100ft away through binoculars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, some did [use them](https://www.inquirer.com/opinion/commentary/voter-suppression-intimidation-mail-in-provisional-ballots-20201106.html)...

[image]

So at least we know that unlike taking photos of ballots, using binoculars was probably legal in some (if not most) places.

Although that photo taken in Pennsylvania shows them in use, it's apparently not permitted in some other places, [e.g.](https://www.lanecounty.org/UserFiles/Servers/Server_3585797/File/Government/County%20Departments/County%20Administration/Operations/County%20Clerk/Elections/Observer%20Rules%20-%20Letterhead.pdf) in Lane County, Oregon,

> Cell phones/cameras/video cameras/binoculars: Turn cell phones off when
> inside the building. **Binoculars are not permitted.** Recording devices of any type, including cameras and video cameras are not permitted.

As for the practicality of it, I'll let someone else comment... but in an AZ [lawsuit](https://www.azmirror.com/2020/11/25/azgop-chair-eyes-nullification-of-presidential-election-in-new-lawsuit/) it was claimed that that was not enough:

> Political parties can appoint observers to watch ballot counting, signature verification and other election-related activities. Ward’s lawsuit alleges election officials kept observers 10 to 12 feet away from the computers where they were verifying signatures, which was too far away to see the signatures themselves. When observers complained, **election workers let them use binoculars, the lawsuit stated, but the observers still weren’t able to read the signatures**.